# Does anyone have a script that will convert \xymatrix to tikzcd?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xy-pic, tikz-cd

I have a long set of lecture notes where the commutative diagrams are written in `xy` using the `\xymatrix` format.  I would like to switch over to `tikz-cd`. The syntax for the two are pretty similar with some minor differences, so it is conceivable to me that someone has either written, or could easily write, a script that will automatically convert all `\xymatrix{...}` occurrences to a `tikz-cd` format that works for all non-exotic commutative diagrams.  If somebody knows of such a script or can give me such a script, I would be very happy!

Note that I am willing to do the effort of fixing diagrams that involve curved lines or other non-standard things if that is too hard for a script.

I am not working on a unix machine although I have access to a Macbook that I could open in unix if necessary.

Here is a sample in `\xymatrix{...}`

```
\xymatrix{\Delta_{q-2}\ar[r]^{F_{q-1}^i}\ar[d]_{F_{q-1}^{j-1}}& \Delta_{q-1}\ar[d]^{F_q^j}\\
 \Delta_{q-1}\ar[r]_{F_{q}^i} & \Delta_q}
```

And the corresponding `tikz-cd`

```
\begin{tikzcd}
\Delta_{q-2}\ar{r}{F_{q-1}^i}\ar{d}[swap]{F_{q-1}^{j-1}}& \Delta_{q-1}\ar{d} {F_q^j}\\ 
\Delta_{q-1}\ar{r}[swap]{F_{q}^i} & \Delta_q
\end{tikzcd}
```

> > Please note that I have at least 50 occurrences of xymatrix so I would like a script that converts a whole file.

Comment: could you provide a sample of code in `xymatrix` and a sample of how you'd like it to look in `tikz-cd`?

Comment: @cmhughes, Ok, I'll do that tonight.

Answer (score 10):

It's not extremely pretty, but it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
use Regexp::Common;

my $file = 'a.tex';             # Change this to your filename
open my $fh, '<', $file;
my $content = do { local $/; <$fh> };

my $bal_rx = $RE{balanced}{-parens=>'{}'};
my $ar_rx = qr/\s*
            \\ar
            (?<dash> @\{-->\} )?
            \[(?<dir> [udlr]+ )\]
            (?: (?<p1> [_^] ) (?<ar1> $bal_rx) )?
            (?: (?<p2> [_^] ) (?<ar2> $bal_rx) )?
            \s*/x;

sub conv_block {
    my $x = shift;
    my @s;
    while ($x =~ s/$ar_rx//){
        my $dir = $+{dir};
        my $dash = $+{dash} ? '[dashed]' : '';
        my ($t1, $t2) = ('', '');
        if ($+{ar1}) {
            $t1 = $+{ar1};
            $t1 = '[swap]' . $t1 if $+{p1} eq '_';
        }
        if ($+{ar2}) {
            $t1 = $+{ar2};
            $t2 = '[swap]' . $t2 if $+{p2} eq '_';
        }
        push @s, "\\ar${dash}{$dir}$t1$t2";
    }
    return $x . ' ' . (join ' ', @s);
}

sub conv_matrix {
    my $matrix = shift;
    $matrix =~ s/^\{(.*)\}$/$1/s;
    my @rows = split /\s* \\\\ \s*/x, $matrix;
    my @cols = map { [split /\s* & \s*/x, $_] } @rows;
    my $res = '';
    $res .= "\\begin{tikzcd}\n";
    $res .= join " \\\\\n", map { join " &\n", map {conv_block $_} @$_ } @cols;
    $res.= "\n\\end{tikzcd}\n";
    return $res;
}

$content =~ s/\\xymatrix $bal_rx/conv_matrix $1/gxe;
open my $out, '>', "${file}.new";
print $out $content;
```

You need Perl and the Regexp::Common library. I haven't extensively tested it, but it works in simple cases.

Comment: I will have to see if I have perl. But can I do this for the whole tex file or do I need to do this occurrence by occurrence. Also this is only a sample. There are other standard xy things I would like to switch to tikzcd.

Comment: You need to input it diagram by diagram. It wouldn't be very easy to rewrite it to work on an entire TeX file (I can try). What other things do you want to convert?

Comment: There are dashed arrows and curved arrows. I don't have many curved arrows so dashed is more important.

Comment: But converting the whole file is more important. There are probably 50 or more xymatrix diagrams in the lecture notes. So doing it one by one is too much. I could essentially do it manually one by one of it was only a couple because the syntax is similar. But I would like to do the whole thing in an automated way.

Comment: There you go, this will now convert the whole file and output the result in a new file.

Comment: Now it will convert dashed arrows.

Comment: Ok. I will try to see if I can get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about perl.  How does it output the new file?  I couldnt find a changed file.

Comment: I got the following errors when compiling: 
Unquoted string "is" may clash with future reserved word at myscript.pl line 1.
Unquoted string "file" may clash with future reserved word at myscript.pl line 2.
Unquoted string "buffer" may clash with future reserved word at myscript.pl line 3.
syntax error at myscript.pl line 1, near "and for "
syntax error at myscript.pl line 2, near "C-x "
"use" not allowed in expression at myscript.pl line 7, at end of line syntax error at myscript.pl line 7, near "use strict"
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at myscript.pl line 8.

Comment: Are you certain that you copied the right thing in myscript.pl? None of the words ("is", "file", "buffer"...) that appear in the errors are in the script, and there is no "use" line 7...

Comment: I thought so, but I will try again.

Comment: I get: Can't locate feature.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /sw/lib/perl5 /sw/lib/perl5/darwin /Library/Perl/Updates/5.8.8 /System/Library/Perl/5.8.8/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.8.8 /Library/Perl/5.8.8/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.8.8 /Library/Perl /Network/Library/Perl/5.8.8/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.8.8 /Network/Library/Perl /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.8.8/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.8.8 /Library/Perl/5.8.6 /Library/Perl/5.8.1 .) at script.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script.pl line 5.

Comment: Your version of Perl is too old. But you can just remove the line saying "use feature ...". You will have to install the Regexp::Common library.

Comment: I updated perl and now it compiled but it simply replaced each xymatrix diagram with a blank one.